# Не могу вставить строку в существующий Excel файл с помощью OpenXmlSDK

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Пытаюсь вставить строку в '*.xlsx' файл использую для этого OpenXml SDK. 
Мой код:

```
using var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("dspreadsheet.xlsx", true);
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
InsertRow(sheetData, 5);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();


static void InsertRow(SheetData sheetData, uint rowIndex)
{
    Row row = new Row();    

    Cell newCell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };            
    var inlineString = new InlineString();
    var text = new Text { Text = "some text for cell" };
    inlineString.Append(text);
    newCell.AppendChild(inlineString);
    row.AppendChild(newCell);        

    var retRow = sheetData.Elements<Row>().ElementAt((int)rowIndex);    
    sheetData.InsertAfter(row, retRow);        
}
```

Я хочу добавить новую строку после 5-й строки. Но когда я открываю сгенерированный файл в Excel 2016, добавленной строки там нет.
Может быть кто-то знает, как можно правильно вставлять строки в существующие .xlsx файлы? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
static void InsertRow(SheetData sheetData, uint rowIndex)
{
    Row row = new Row();    

    Cell newCell = new Cell { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };            
    var inlineString = new InlineString();
    var text = new Text { Text = "some text for cell" };
    inlineString.Append(text);
    newCell.AppendChild(inlineString);
    row.AppendChild(newCell);        

    var retRow = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Last();    
    sheetData.InsertAfter(row, retRow);        
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]